# How to loop through functions dependent on previous function?

Tags: unity, c#

In Unity, I need to generate a series of platforms in a specific order for a sidescroller I am working on. The issue is that the generation of the next platform is dependent of the previous platform meaning I can not generate the next platform before the previous platform is made. In this case I cannot predict where the next platform will be at since its length is based off randomized parameters. Also I the generation function is based off of multiple scripts so it has to go through multiple scripts before the generation is complete.

I am currently using a Bool function to wait for the completion of the generation but I do not think this is the appropriate way to go about this. What would be an appropriator structure for calling multiple functions dependent on the previous call?

**This function is used to call the functions to generate the platform**

```
    public void GeneratePlatformSequence ()
{
//For loop to 
    for (int i = 0; i < TerrainSequence.Count; i++) { 
        bool isComplete = TerrainSequence [i].Transition (TerrainSequence [i+1], new Vector3(50*1,0,0));
    }
}
```

**Abstract class for Platform Generation**

```C#
public abstract class TerrainMesh : MonoBehaviour {

    public abstract bool Transition(TerrainMesh CurrPlatform, Vector3 LastPosition);

}
```

**One of the mesh generation classes I use to create the platform**

```C#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GroundTerrain : TerrainMesh {

    public override bool Transition(TerrainMesh CurrPlatform, Vector3 LastPosition) {
        bool isStepComplete =   GroundTransition(CurrPlatform, LastPosition);
        return isStepComplete;
    }

    public bool GroundTransition (TerrainMesh CurrPlatform, Vector3 LastPosition){
        if (CurrPlatform is WaterTerrain) {
            print ("Generating WaterTerrain");
//Here is where I generate the Actual mesh for the platform.
            bool GeneratedMesh = MeshGenerate ();
            return GeneratedMesh ;
        }


        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your mesh generation is done on a single thread (no coroutines), then there is no need to wait for completion using a boolean variable.

`GeneratePlatformSequence()` will not return until all the function calls within `GeneratePlatformSequence` have finished. In other words, `GeneratePlatformSequence()` will wait for `Transition()` to finish, and `Transition()` will wait for `GroudTransition()` to finish, and so forth.

That means you don't need the bool returns. C# will wait for function calls to finish.

Comment: Wow, I did not know that the For loop will wait until the function is done. This makes my life much easier, Thank You!